# Potential Personal Data In Posts

Tags: support, inappropriate-content

What is Stack Overflow, or in general, Stack Exchange's standing on (innocently positioned) personally identifiable data?

For instance, this following post has information that may be PID. It may or may not belong directly to the author, but could be an innocent byproduct of a naive user not understanding the implications!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032649/whats-wrong-in-this-query

What are the guidelines in such a case? Should we simply edit it and replace it with Chuck Norris' data, or flag it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should we simply edit it and replace it with Chuck Norris' data, or flag it?

Please do both.  Edit out the sensitive data, then flag it for a moderator and we'll escalate it to a Stack Exchange employee who can delete the earlier revisions.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I've already flagged the post, but I'll do the edit now, if someone hasn't done it already.

Comment: Aaaaaand I see that you are a Ninja speed lizard!

Comment: FYI: Data still exists in the revision history of the three answers. I flagged one, then realized the other two had it.